# Selenium IDE doesn't open webpages that return a json response

Tags: json, firefox, selenium

I have a big Selenium test suite that's testing a web service. Given an input url, the web service returns either a regular html response or a json response. The test suite is being executed with Firefox's Selenium IDE. The tests call the open command on a given url and then verify stuff on the returned json/html. It used to work great until for some reason Firefox has stopped opening the jsons automatically. Instead of opening the json response as if it were a regular web page, Firefox asks "What should Firefox do with this file" and prompts me to select a program to open the file with.

How do I force Selenium IDE to make Firefox display the json responses as it used to?

Comment: Firefox probably updated without you realising it. What version are you running?

Comment: @Arran: You're almost right. Turns out I've used an older version of Firefox. Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cases like these are usually Firefox & Selenium IDE version incompatibility. This can be from using a much newer version or an old version of Firefox that the IDE doesn't *quite* support.

In your case it appears to be an older version issue.

The first step you should do is update both the IDE & Firefox and take it from there.

The [release notes](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SeIDEReleaseNotes) also detail what version (range) of Firefox it *generally* supports.